# How to convert attributes from XML to values and values to subvalues...?

Tags: xml, bash, xslt

here is what I would like to do:

Convert this XML:

```
<book author="Name" year="2000">Book title</book>
```

To this XML:

```
<book><author>Name</author><year>2000</year><value>Book title</value></book>
```

I would like to do it with xslt or something I can run from bash...

Thanks.

Comment: So convert with a script, e.g. bash; or transform with XSLT?

Comment: any one of those would be ok... I just don't know how :(

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that uses the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern -- the use and overriding of the Identity rule. Extensive explanation is also provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <value>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </value>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<book author="Name" year="2000">Book title</book>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<book><author>Name</author><year>2000</year><value>Book title</value></book>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **[identity rule/template](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies every node "as-is".
2. We override the identity rule with a template matching any attribute. It creates an element whose name is the name of the matched attribute and whose only text-node child is the value of the matched attribute.
3. Finally, we override the identity rule with a template that matches any text node. It simply outputs this node wrapped in a `value` parent element.

**Do note**: The use and overriding of the identity rule is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern.

> I would like to do it with xslt or
>   something I can run from bash...

**Most XSLT processors come with a command-line utility** that invokes an XSLT transformation from the command line. Read your XSLT processor's documentation.

Comment: Great! just what I need... now I only need to hide elements like <value>  </value> if source is a formated xml (with some extra whitespaces...)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using xmlstarlet & Bash (it doesn't keep the tag order author-year-subvalue though):

```
(
i=0
xmlstr='<book author="Name" year="2000">Book title</book>'

while IFS="" read -r -d $'\n' xpath; do 
  ((i+=1))
  name="$(printf '%s' "$xmlstr" | xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "/${xpath}" -v "name(.)")" 
  value="$(printf '%s' "$xmlstr" | xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "/${xpath}" -v '.')" 
  if [[ $i -eq 1 ]] || [[ "${xpath%/*}" != "${rootxpath}" ]]; then
    rootxpath="${xpath%/*}"
    subvalue="$(printf '%s' "$xmlstr" | xml sel -T -t -m "/${xpath}" -v '..')"
    xmlstr="$(printf '%s' "$xmlstr" | xmlstarlet ed -u "/${xpath}/.." -v "" --subnode "." --type elem -n "$name" -v "$value" --subnode "." --type elem -n subvalue -v "$subvalue" )"
  else
    xmlstr="$(printf '%s' "$xmlstr" | xmlstarlet ed --subnode "/${xpath}/.." --type elem -n "$name" -v "$value")"
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "xpath: $xpath" "name: $name" "value: $value" "subvalue: $subvalue"; echo
done < <(echo "$xmlstr" | xmlstarlet el -a | LC_ALL=C sort -ru | grep -E '/@[^@]+$')  # only get absolute paths that have attributes

# delete all attributes, move subvalues to the last position and format XML output
xmlstr="$(printf '%s\n' "$xmlstr" | xmlstarlet ed -d "//*/@*" -m "//subvalue" "." | tidy -q -xml | xmlstarlet fo -R -o -s 3 -)"

printf '%s\n\n' "$xmlstr"

printf '%s\n' "$xmlstr" | xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//book/*[1]" -v "name(.)" -o ': ' -v . -n
printf '%s\n' "$xmlstr" | xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//book/*[2]" -v "name(.)" -o ': ' -v . -n
printf '%s\n' "$xmlstr" | xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//book/*[3]" -v "name(.)" -o ': ' -v . -n

)
```

The main output should be:

```
<book>
   <year>2000</year>
   <author>Name</author>
   <subvalue>Book title</subvalue>
</book>
```